# import data from the objects created in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have created an app in salesforce platform,

i have some primitive records in that, i need to import them in visual force.

For example,if we create a record in Account in Salesforce,,,

like charles,Jennifer,Tom and all

i need to import them in visualforce and do things which i can do in salesforce..please help me out with this

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Before you go about doing this, you'll need to become familiar with some of the more basic concepts.

- An excellent [introduction](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Force.com_Tutorial:_An_Introduction_to_Visualforce).
- There's some detailed documentation on Visualforce and using controllers [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller.htm).
- [Visualforce cookbook](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Force_Platform_Cookbook). Lot's of worked examples.